# Route works in browser, fails in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2, rspec-rails

This question has probably been asked a dozen times on Stack Overflow (e.g. ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8647491/306084)), ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7944668/306084)), ([3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7859032/306084)), ([4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6756896/306084)), ([5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11074404/306084))) but every time the answer seems to be different and none of them have helped me. I'm working on a Rails Engine and I'm finding that Rspec2 gets route errors, but I can reach the routes in the browser. Here's the situation:

- In the engine's `routes.rb`:

  ```
  resources :mw_interactives, :controller => 'mw_interactives', :constraints => { :id => /\d+/ }, :except => :show

  # This is so we can build the InteractiveItem at the same time as the Interactive
  resources :pages, :controller => 'interactive_pages', :constraints => { :id => /\d+/ }, :only => [:show] do
    resources :mw_interactives, :controller => 'mw_interactives', :constraints => { :id => /\d+/ }, :except => :show
  end
  ```
- Excerpted output of `rake routes`:

  ```
       new_mw_interactive GET    /mw_interactives/new(.:format)                              lightweight/mw_interactives#new {:id=>/\d+/}
                          ...
  new_page_mw_interactive GET    /pages/:page_id/mw_interactives/new(.:format)               lightweight/mw_interactives#new {:id=>/\d+/, :page_id=>/\d+/}
  ```
- And my test, from one of the controller specs (`describe Lightweight::MwInteractivesController do`):

  ```
  it 'shows a form for a new interactive' do
    get :new
  end
  ```

...which gets this result:

```
Failure/Error: get :new
ActionController::RoutingError:
  No route matches {:controller=>"lightweight/mw_interactives", :action=>"new"}
```

...and yet when I go to that route in the browser, it works exactly as intended.

What am I missing here?

ETA: To clarify a point Andreas raises: this is a Rails Engine, so rspec runs in a dummy application which includes the engine's routes in a namespace:

```
 mount Lightweight::Engine => "/lightweight"
```

...so the routes shown in `rake routes` are prefaced with `/lightweight/`. That's why the route shown in the Rspec error doesn't seem to match what's in `rake routes`. But it does make the debugging an extra step wonkier.

ETA2: Answering Ryan Clark's comment, this is the action I'm testing:

```
 module Lightweight
   class MwInteractivesController < ApplicationController
     def new
       create
     end
```

...and that's it.

Comment: @zetetic: yes, it is. I suppose I should have said so - I'll edit now to add that.

Comment: Can you show your :new definition in the controller?

Comment: What is the subject of the spec? Is it the namespaced controller class name? Controller specs don't do any actual routing -- the error message is likely misleading you.

Comment: @zetetic, I've added the class definition from the spec - is that what you mean by "subject"?

Comment: I appreciate the patience you guys have with this, by the way. I was wailing and gnashing my teeth, and I have the code in front of me.

Comment: The subject is the instance being tested, so `describe MyInteractivesController` implies a subject with a class of `MyInteractivesController`.

Comment: Oops I see you already updated the question. So RSpec is not building the spec properly, probably because it is not dealing with the namespace. Does it work if you strip off the `Lightweight::' part?

Another thought here is to not use controller specs at all, and use request specs instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for this. Right at the top of the spec, I added this code:

```
render_views
before do
  # work around bug in routing testing
  @routes = Lightweight::Engine.routes
end
```

...and now the spec runs without the routing error. But I don't know why this works, so if someone can post an answer which explains it, I'll accept that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the might be something wrong higher up in you specs

how did the "lightweight" get into this line :controller=>"lightweight/mw_interactives"

the route says

```
new_mw_interactive GET    /mw_interactives/new(.:format)
```

not

```
new_mw_interactive GET    /lightweight/mw_interactives/new(.:format)
```

Comment: The "lightweight" part of the URL is because the controllers are from a namespaced engine.

Comment: I am starting on my first rails engine in a few days. If I get the same problem I'll bee back.

Answer (score 0):

add a file spec/routing/root_routing_spec.rb

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "routes for Widgets" do
  it "routes /widgets to the widgets controller" do
    { :get => "/" }.should route_to(:controller => "home", :action => "index")
  end
end
```

then add a file spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe HomeController do

    context "GET index" do
    before(:each) do
      get :index
    end
    it {should respond_with :success }
    it {should render_template(:index) }

   end
end
```

Comment: Why, and how would it answer my question? If you're asking if I have other specs that pass, the answer is "yes, dozens of them."